# difference between manually firing a javascript event and triggering default event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Let us say I have a check box and a textbox. On click of check box I set some value in textBox.

**AngularJs Implementation**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterPrivateDocModel" ng-click="filterPrivateDoc(filterPrivateDocModel)">
<input st-search="target" ng-model="text" ng-change="setVal()"/>
```

```
$scope.filterPrivateDoc=function(val) {
  if (val) {
    angular.element('[ng-model="text"]').change();
  }
}

$scope.setVal=function() {
  angular.element('[ng-model="text"]').focus();
  $scope.text = 'Private';
}
```

It correctly sets the value of textBox on click of checkBox with value 'Private', but it does not filter the value, though my I am trying to call **onchange event of javascript** (using ng-change in angular) manually but still it does not work.

But the moment I start typing something on textbox any character it triggers the setValue (onchange event of javascript) and filters the data. Why ??

So my question are

(1)  **What is the difference between manually calling a javascript onchange
       event and default trigger??**

(2)  **And how can I make it to work in my case without typing anything on
         textbox and filter starts working.**

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you don't do that. The whole idea is that you **separate the data model, the controlling code and the view** completely. Your solution should let the framework (angular) deal with refreshing the view when the model changes, so use the model to trigger that refresh.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterPrivateDocModel" ng-click="filterPrivateDoc(filterPrivateDocModel)">
<input st-search="target" ng-model="text" ng-change="setVal()"/>
```

```
$scope.filterPrivateDoc=function(val) {
  if (val) {
    setTextVal($scope);
  }
}

$scope.setVal=function() {
  angular.element('[ng-model="text"]').focus();
  setTextVal($scope);
}

function setTextVal($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'Private';
}
```